# list of all docker status types

Tags: python, docker

Where can I get a list of all the docker status types? e.g. **Up**, **Exited**, **Created**.

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS       PORTS                                       NAMES
f0771636c8ab   registry:2   "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   25 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp   registry
```

**This next part may be unrelated since it could be a completely different "status"**. but in the docker python api I've also seen status values of the following.  I looked through the Python docker code and it doesn't appear to include these string so I think they're originating within docker itself and not the python api.

- preparing
- downloading
- pushing
- restarting
- running
- waiting
- verifying checksum
- etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Docker HTTP API, the [Inspect a Container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerInspect) API call (`GET /containers/{id}/json`) includes a `Stats` field with OpenAPI type `ContainerState`.  That contains a field `Status`.  Its possible values are `"created"` `"running"` `"paused"` `"restarting"` `"removing"` `"exited"` `"dead"`

The higher-level Docker SDKs and CLI tools all ultimately wrap this API, so any container status from docker-py or `docker ps` will be derived from one of these values.  The `Up 3 hours` output, for example, looks like a combination of a `running` state and a calculated container uptime.  The list you quote largely doesn't look like container statuses ("push" is not a valid action on a container) and it might go with some other object.